# Particles Emitted Far Away From Emitter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, particles

[image: You can see the particles]

As you can see, there are particles being emitted that aren't even close to the emitter object (underneath the rocket). They are several blend units back and down. Does anybody have an idea as to what's happening? Let me know any other info I need to put.

[image]
Here is my particle System settings

Comment: Please show your Particle System and Any Forces and Obstacles.  We see the flow only in the image in your question at  this time.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I have uploaded my particle settings, and there are no force fields at the moment

Comment: Show the emitter mesh in Edit Mode.  With all vertices selected. Keystroke A. Isolated vertices will not render typically, thus they can have some subtle effects, They  can produce particles. It is quite possible you have a stray vertices.

Comment: Get a fresh start, if your particle system is not too complicated. Delete your current emitter mesh to reduce the possibility  of stray vertices.  Emit from faces rather than vertices.  Faces are more visible. Use a circle or bottom of cylinder.